# adding php time

Tags: php, time

i have a value store in variables as 11:30.

I need to add a minutes to this variable..Example, adding 15 minutes to make it 11:45

can i do that ? i tried to use time() but it will give current time... but i want to add time to the specified variable

Answer (score 2):

```
date("H:i", strtotime("11:30 +15 minutes"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$time = "11:30";
$minutes = 15; 
$time = strtotime($time) + $minutes * 60;
echo date("H:i", $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
$str = "11:30";
list($h, $m) = explode(":", $str);
$tm = mktime($h, $m + 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
echo date("H:i", $tm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what your asking for using the built in PHP methods [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [date_add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php).